# How to hide XHR Requests in a react single page application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side

In react when data is fetched from an endpoint , the endpoint is visible in chrome's devtools under network tab . How can I just hide it ? Does server side rendering solve this issue ?

Comment: You can't hide it. You can however secure it with use of authorization headers if that is of benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in react js the only way is to secure api routes with jwt and etc ...